Mac sometimes boots into recovery, but restart solves issue - until the next time
I have an issue with my MacBook Pro M1 2020, running Sonoma.
Occasionally, my Mac won't boot. In this situation, when I plug in the power cable - even just or a second - it boots to Recovery. A few times I have recovered it, but discovered that simply restarting the computer (without recovering) takes me to the desktop as usual. The desktop shows the battery is full (suggesting the lack of battery power isn't the reason it's not booting).
In other words, it's booting into recovery, but I don't need to recover it - I can just restart it and all appears well for while, until it spontaneously says it needs to recover again days or weeks later (which is solved by a restart...)
I have reinstalled the OS multiple times. Disk Utility shows no issues. System report shows battery is Normal. Apple Diagnostics reports no issues. My hunch is power circuitry.
I could take it into the Genius Bar, but the problem is tricky to recreate and system reports suggests there is no problem?
Thanks in advance!

Do you have FileVault enabled?
